# gstreamer/libsoup can't connect on eth1?

Tags: http, networking, gstreamer

I'm running gstreamer in an embedded Linux environment with two network interfaces, eth0 and eth1, using something like this pipeline:

```
gst-launch souphttpsrc location=http://something.com/something.mp4 ! filesink location=./something.mp4
```

eth0 is on my development LAN and eth1 is on a LAN with internet gateway. wget can retrieve files via http from either, but the gstreamer/libsoup setup only works with URLs on the eth0 subnet. For eth1, it just sits there like it can't connect.

Do I need to set something up in gst/libsoup to access via eth1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was down to some DNS misconfiguration, not interface related.